# Image magick: takes too much time at linux server

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I am facing an issue with time taken by imagemagic to execute the commands on my server. I also tried to make thread control from 20(default) to 1 but, no improvements.

Here are some of the commands we fire and time took for them on server. Is there any way to reduce this execution time?

1. /usr/bin/convert source1.jpeg -resize 4518x3013! output.png

   real    0m13.150s
   user    0m18.320s
   sys     0m2.029s
2. /usr/bin/convert output.png -crop 2408x3010+1053+0 +repage cropped.png

   real    0m5.978s
   user    0m5.043s
   sys     0m0.881s
3. /usr/bin/convert destination.png -draw image over 564,564+2408+3010 'cropped.png'  output.png

   real    0m10.085s
   user    0m11.160s
   sys     0m1.710s

---

Updated Information

identify -version command output:
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-08-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: Copyright ( c ) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  Features: DPC OpenMP
  Delegates: bzlib freetype gslib jng jpeg png ps tiff zlib

Server configuration:
  OS version is centos 6
  RAM 32GB

source1.jpeg([link](http://solacetechnologies.co.in/projects/1409319136.jpeg))
First command executed with -bench 5 and returned below output.
Performance[1]: 5i 0.095ips 1.000e 90.970u 0:52.550
Performance[2]: 5i 0.104ips 0.522e 92.310u 0:48.110
Performance[3]: 5i 0.090ips 0.485e 93.420u 0:55.770
Performance[4]: 5i 0.086ips 0.474e 91.180u 0:58.230
Performance[5]: 5i 0.091ips 0.488e 94.850u 0:55.030

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: How was Imagemagick installed on the server? Are OpenMP or OpenCL features enabled? Please show us the output of `identify -version` and run the same commands in your example with `-bench 10` option.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-08-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype gslib jng jpeg png ps tiff zlib

SERVER
Os version is centos 6
RAM: 32 GB

Comment: Calling imagemagick multiple times result in multiple, unnecessary encodings and decodings of intermediate steps. It should be significantly faster if you write a small program to do all the operations at once.

Comment: Why would you pass a non-integer size to `-resize`? What is the point of telling us how long it takes to crop/resize an image when you don't tell us how big the original image is? Are all the steps part of a single, larger processing chain? If so, you may be better off using a longer command that does everything in one go - or using MPC - the Magick Pixel Cache. Are you really running from the command-line, or is your system actually written in Perl or PHP or something that could use ImageMagick bindings rather than forking and execing? Can you make a RAMdisk for intermediate files maybe?

Comment: How can anyone say if your system is slow when we don't know if is a Raspberry Pi or 16 core server? Can you reduce the quality setting? Is an 8-bit quantisation good enough (Q8 vs Q16)?

Comment: @emcconville Imagemagick is installed as OpenMP. Here is the output for two commands you mentioend -
identify -version 
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-08-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright ( c ) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype gslib jng jpeg png ps tiff zlib

Os version is centos 6
Ram 32gb

/usr/bin/convert source1.jpeg(600x400) -resize 4518.01x3013.01! -bench 5 output.png
Performance[1]: 5i 0.106ips 1.000e 91.320u 0:46.950

Comment: @that other guy Yes. Thats what is the plan. But these individual commands are also taking huge time so first wanted to optimize it.

Comment: @Mark Setchell  Sorry for the incomplete info. Here is the original image [link](http://solacetechnologies.co.in/projects/1409319136.jpeg). 
Yes, its part of longer chain, but the chain can reduce once we get these individual commands execute faster.
We are running these from command-line.
Here are server details again -

"Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-08-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright ( c ) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype gslib jng jpeg png ps tiff zlib"

"OS: centos 6, Ram 32 GB"

Comment: @SagarS. Please click `edit` underneath your question and supply all the information requested within an updated, complete question rather than as an endless sequence of badly formatted addenda - I think you will get a proper answer if you do that, and you risk being put on hold if you do not.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks Mark. Question is updated with related information.

Comment: The image you have linked to is 600x400pixels. Is that really your starting image that you resize?

Comment: @Mark - Yes Mark its same image we are re sizing.

Comment: @Mark We are in to printing business and has to create output image with 300dpi for printer. 
When user provides images, sometimes they are of small size/resolution like provided one which we need to resize. 
At last operation we also change its dpi to 300.

Comment: @Mark even resizing 3648x2736 = 3996x3003 (300 pixel larger than basic image) still getting more time.
real    0m10.560s
user    0m20.337s
sys     0m2.181s

Comment: It may be related to the fact that you have `OpenMP` configured. Have a look here http://mapopa.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/php-image-slow-smp-magick-on-ubuntu.html    Note that the first line should be `build-dep` not `buil-dep`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks Mark your last posted blog [link](http://mapopa.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/php-image-slow-smp-magick-on-ubuntu.html) really works for us its save 60% execution time. Now we are also going to optimize commands. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Let me know if my suggestion below helps too please.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you any faster?

```
convert input.png -quality 80% -resize 4518x3013! \
    \( +clone -crop 2408x3010+1053+0 +repage \) \
    -geometry +564+564 -composite output.png
```

Comment: Yes, it reduces the time by 50%, but we don't want to reduce the quality of image. We want to keep original quality of image. I know at PC sometimes barely see the difference at quality with 80-90%. But after printing on large cavas, it becomes more visible.      
We want to keep original quality of photo uploaded by user.

Comment: What if you change the quality to 80-90% then?

Answer (score 0):

For really fast PNG writing, use -quality 10 for drawings, -quality 11 for photos.  This should cut your PNG-writing time by a factor of five.

The "quality" number doesn't affect image quality when writing a PNG.  It only affects the compression effectiveness.

Comment: Hi Glenn, Most interesting! Is this explained or documented anywhere please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, see imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality (which you can find from the main www.imagemagick.org page by selecting options, then -quality).  Incidentally, that page mentions -quality 0 for fastest compression, but that seems to revert to the slow default quality now.